# How to check which week and month days given interval consist of?

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

Assume that I have two LocalDate objects, fromDate and toDate.
I need to know which week days are there inside the interval - Monday, Tuesday, etc.
And, I'd like to know also which daysOfMonth - 1st, 2nd, or, for example 20th only - from 20 to 23rd.
Is there any useful tool/method in the Joda time library which cah help me? I'm not asking about particular algorithm, I could write it by myself, but I'm not sure about Joda functionality - maybe it already has things I could reuse.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is about as close as you'll get I think :

[Days between](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/Days.html#daysBetween%28org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant%29)

or maybe something like this (assumes only ever two different months) :

```
public Boolean dayOfMonthExistInPeriod(final int dayOfMonth, final LocalDate from, final LocalDate until){
        final DateMidnight tested = new DateMidnight(from.getYear(), from.getMonthOfYear(), dayOfMonth);
        final DateMidnight tested2 = new DateMidnight(until.getYear(), until.getMonthOfYear(), dayOfMonth);
        final Interval interval = new Interval(from.toDateMidnight(), until.toDateMidnight());
        return interval.contains(tested) && interval.contains(tested2);
    }
```

Comment: But it will allow me just only count how many days was between two dates, which is not so important for me. Of course, if this amount was > 7 then I can be sure that this interval includes all the week days, from Mon to Sun. But, what if interval less than 7 days? I don't know whether it includes Monday unless I will iterate over every day which looks like a nightmare... It gets worse if I start thinking about how to decide whether this interval include 28th day of month or no..

Comment: its hardly a nightmare - you wouldn't need to iterate over every one to find out if a dayofweek was included; there are the dayOfMonth() and dayOfWeek() properties too.

Comment: Class Days does not consist of these properties, it's LocalDate properties.. so you suggest to iterate over every day in the interval to check dayOfMonth() and dayOfWeek()  ?

Comment: No I don't suggest that. I am not sure of you exact requirements, but its  pretty simple calculation to find out whether a given date is present, or a given day of week - without iterating over every day in the period.

Comment: I'm sure that if it is simple you wouldn't mind write short simple code snippet to calculate whether interval 11.04.2012-02.05.2012 contains 31th day of month

Comment: what if the period goes over three months ?

Comment: Why does your method return `Boolean` instead of `boolean`? Do you ever expect to return null?

Comment: @SteveKuo I have got into the habit of not using the primitives for such reasons as being null safe and having built in additional functionality. I assume the jvm handles any significant optimization.

Comment: The issue isn't optimization, but semantics. Looking at the signature of your method implies that null can be returned. By using `Boolean` instead of `boolean` you are introducing unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @NimChimpsky the task is no longer actual, however will +1 just for the attention and your time

Comment: Update: The midnight-related classes and methods in Joda-Time 2.3 are deprecated. Instead call the DateTime method `withTimeAtStartOfDay`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isDayBetween(int dtc, DateTime from, DateTime to)
   {
      final int dayOfWeekFrom = from.dayOfWeek().get();
      final int daysBetween = Days.daysBetween(from, to).getDays();
      if (dtc >= dayOfWeekFrom && dtc <= (dayOfWeekFrom + daysBetween))
         return true;
      return false;
   }
```

Use method

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
final DateTime from = dtf.parseDateTime("2000-07-08");
final DateTime to = dtf.parseDateTime("2000-07-13");
boolean res = isDayBetween(from, to, DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )
    .plusDays( 1 )
    .getDayOfWeek()  // Returns a `DayOfWeek` enum object such as `DayOfWeek.MONDAY`.
```

…and…

```
java.time.LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )
    .plusDays( 1 )
    .getDayOfMonth()  // Returns an integer number, 1-31.
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted both the legacy date-time classes from the earliest Java and the *Joda-Time* project. Both *Joda-Time* and *java.time*/JSR 310 are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne, so the concepts are closely aligned.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.FEBRUARY , 4 ) ;
```

Calculating number of days elapsed is easy with the `ChronoUnit` enum.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

That calculation is made using the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach is generally the wise way to define spans of time.

> I need to know which week days are there inside the interval - Monday, Tuesday, etc.

There’s a class for that: [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) defining seven objects, one for each day of the week. The [`EnumSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) class is a highly-optimized implementation of [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) for collecting `DayOfWeek` objects. A `Set` absorbs/ignores duplicates, so we will end up with a distinct collection.

```
final int countDaysInWeek = DayOfWeek.values().length ;  // Seven days in a week.
Set< DayOfWeek > dows = EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class ) ;
LocalDate ld = start ;
while ( ld.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    dows.add( ld.getDayOfWeek() ) ;  // Add each date’s day-of-week to our collection.
    if ( dows.size() == countDaysInWeek ) { break ; }  // Bail out of this loop after collecting all the days of the week.
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Increment to the next day, to setup the next loop. The java.time classes use immutable objects, so we are generating a fresh object here rather than modifying the original.
}
```

> And, I'd like to know also which daysOfMonth - 1st, 2nd, or, for example 20th only - from 20 to 23rd.

You *could* collect the number of the day-of-month, but I doubt that is what you want.

```
List< Integer > dayOfMonthNumbers = new ArrayList<>() ;
LocalDate ld = start ;
while ( ld.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    dayOfMonthNumbers.add( ld.getDayOfMonth() ) ;
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Increment to next date.
}
```

If you roll into another month you will end up with a list like: `29 , 30 , 1 , 2`. I suspect you will find it more useful to use a collection of `LocalDate` objects rather than a mere day-of-month number.

```
List< LocalDate > dates = new ArrayList<>() ;
LocalDate ld = start ;
while ( ld.isBefore( stop ) ) {
    dates.add( ld ) ;
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Increment to next date.
}
```

From there you can generate Strings to represent those date values using `DateTimeFormatter`.  Search Stack Overflow for more info, as that has been covered many times already.

### *ThreeTen-Extra* & `LocalDateRange`

Tip: If you add the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project, you can represent your span of time using the [`LocalDateRange`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) class.

```
LocalDateRange range = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).